# Je suis touché / infiniment touché ?

Tags: vocabulaire

What's the difference between these two sentences:

> Je suis touché par tes mots.

and

> Je suis infiniment touché par tes mots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Insérer *infiniment* devant le participe passé *touché* ajoute simplement du poids au fait que l'on est *touché*. On aurait pu dire aussi: *je suis très touché...*, *infiniment* étant plus fort que *très*.